# Local Server for Plotly Dash Application Takes Forever on Initial Load

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a Plotly Dash app that I run locally on my 2020 M1 Pro Macbook Pro. When I spin up a local server for the first time either A) after a restart or B) for the first time in a while (~24hrs), it takes almost an hour for the server to get up and running. After that initial time, however, if I restart the server it will do so within a minute.

I developed the app as a tool to facilitate my personal trading processes, and it has grown rather complex, but I imagine the complexity pales in comparison to other enterprise applications. My best guess is that the loading time has something to do with cacheing, though I am struggling to validate that or debug the issue generally.

Does anyone know what may be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: When the server is taking an hour to load, stop program and look at the stack trace.  That will tell you what function your program is currently executing that is taking so long.  Throw some print statements throughout your code to notify you when different parts of your code are being executed.  It's probably nothing to do with Dash but whatever you are running before the server interface.